# advice for create a class for manage files in android

Tags: java, android, file

I'm developing an android app that need to create/modify some files during its execution. I know that in android to manage files I need to use Context's methods sub-classes. But in my app the class that has an access to files is not an Activity class, a class that I'm used to use when I need some graphical functionality (interact with user, display images ecc..).

In my mind the class that manage my files is used to make some cryptographic operations, the graphical classes are other (in a mvc structure the class that manage my files is on model part, not in the view). I cannot find any solutions that use Context classes in this way, without any graphical purposes. What kind of characteristics should my class have to implement I/O files operations (declaration on XML and effective type)?

Thanks

Comment: Where and how you suppose to use your FileUtils class, within Android Context(activity, service, etc)?

Comment: I see that the only way in android that I can use to manage files is to use Context methods, but in my opinion this implies a weird dependancy between a model class and a view, in java I use File streams whithout the need to pass upper level objects (Activity in my situation), this seems quite strange to me that I came from Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a context reference from your activity to the datamodel using getApplicationContext().

```
yourFileUtilObject.objectMethod(getApplicationContext());
```

In your fileUtil class your methods that require context will take a paramater of type Context.

```
public void objectMethod(Context context){
    // your io code with refernce to context when needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always get an abstract representation of the file (java.io.File) in Android Context class, then pass  this java.io.File object into your FileUtils class, for example inside a Activity class:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ... ...
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "sample.txt");
    FileUtils.encrypt(file);
    ... ...
  }

}
```

So you can create you FileUtils as a POJO class that is decoupled from Android Context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps but this is an example of how I use file output to an external storage in my own logging class without any reference to the activity class:

```
String logFilePath = "path/on/sd/card";
File logFileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), logFilePath);
if (!logFileDir.exists()) {
  if(!logFileDir.mkdirs()) {
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Could not create directory: " + logFileDir.getAbsolutePath());
    return;
  }
}

...

String logFilePathName = logFilePath + "/" + dateTime + logFileNameSuffix;
File logFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), logFilePathName);
try {
  logFilePrintWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(logFile));
  logFilePrintWriter.println(dateTime + " - " + firstMsg);
  logFilePrintWriter.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
  Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Could not create log file: " + logFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```